# How can I make my flask server emit messages through flask socket-IO to specific client

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I cant find any good documentation about this topic.

I have a server that provides authentication to clients and a simple REST API.

The server also running on a background_thread a socket-IO connection for communication with computers.

I want to save every session that opened with a computer on the socket-IO in database, and when user click a button in some page then my server start emitting messages to a specific computer using his saved session id.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

The `sid` session id assigned to each client is also the name of a room that has only that client in it. To send an event to a client, just send it to a room with the `sid` that you want. For example:

```
emit('some-event', {'data': 'foo'}, room=sid, namespace='/test')
```

Comment: OK, so in my 'connect' event at the server i am saving the request.namespace.socket.sessid into the mongoDB (my flask version is 0.10.1), then when user click button i use emit() and send to the 'room' argument the value that i pre-saved in DB? The sessid is a StringField right?

Comment: The expression that you want is `request.sid`, but other than that yes, that's how it would work.

Comment: I changed `request.namespace.socket.sessid` to `request.sid` as you said, now i'm going to build a testing socketio client, though I think my flask version is outdated and doesn't has yet the `request.sid` because I saw somewhere at the web that I need more updated version, by the way thanks for all your help, it's really nice to have some help from an expert .